# Use Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore with database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement a 3 legged authentication in my app to the Google API, to be able to access registered users' Google Calendars.

In the [quickstart Ruby guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ruby), this command comes up that as far as I understand should point to the user's tokens:

```
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: CREDENTIALS_PATH)
```

It expects the tokens stored [in a file](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/googleauth/0.5.0/Google/Auth/Stores/FileTokenStore) (or [Redis](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/googleauth/0.5.0/Google/Auth/Stores/RedisTokenStore)), but (of course) I store each user's tokens in my database (Postgres).

Have I understand the purpose of the command wrongly or otherwise - how do I use it with a database store?

[Official documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/googleauth/0.5.0/Google/Auth/TokenStore)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I implemented it myself based on @Rafe's answer. Just wanted to share in case someone wants to copy the ActiveRecord / Database store implementation:

```
module Google
  module Auth
    module Stores
      class DatabaseTokenStore < Google::Auth::TokenStore
        def load(id)
          user = User.find(id)
          {
            "client_id": ENV['google_client_id'],
            "access_token": user.token,
            "refresh_token": user.refresh_token,
            "scope": ENV['google_scopes'],
            "expiration_time_millis": user.token_expires_at
          }.to_json
        end
        def store(id, token)
          user = User.find(id)
          hsh = JSON.parse(token)
          user.update(
            token: hsh["access_token"],
            token_expires_at: hsh["expiration_time_millis"] / 1000
          )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the code that utilize this class please?

Comment: @AbubakrA.Hafiz the web example in the readme is useful: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby#example-web

but modify the token_store like `token_store = Google::Auth::Stores:: DatabaseTokenStore.new` You'll also need a users table with `token`, `token_expires_at`, and `refresh_token` columns in order for the `User` model to update correctly with this token store.

Answer (score 5):

Implement it yourself, according to the [the readme](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby#storage):

> Custom storage implementations can also be used. See [token_store.rb](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/master/lib/googleauth/token_store.rb) for additional details.

It shouldn't be too hard to implement the `load(id)`, `store(id, token)` and `delete(id)` with ActiveRecord (or another ORM) by the looks of the mentioned files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still buffled though that this hasn't be given more attention?

Comment: @FellowStranger if you come from a different language it might take a while to get used to [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) for solving something like this :) A more explicit example is given by the [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store#configuration) gem for what methods must be implemented if you supply your own implementation.

Comment: Wow, thanks again! (Realizing now though that this simple API integration will take a lot more time than anticipated.. :/ )

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck! Don't forget to mark an answer if it helped you for those shiny internet points ;)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer above it's good and I recommend it https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267763/473040, but  I find it useful to store everything for future debugging. Also simplicity is beautiful :)

Add json  column to Postgres DB table (or serialise text field in other db)

```
class AddGooglePhotosTokensToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :google_photo_tokens, :json
  end
end
```

class:

```
class GoogleAuthDbStore < Google::Auth::TokenStore
  def load(id)
    user = User.find(id)
    user.google_photo_tokens
  end
  def store(id, tokens)
    user = User.find(id)
    user.google_photo_tokens = tokens
    user.save!
  end

  def delete id
    user = User.find(id)
    user.google_photo_tokens = nil
    user.save!
  end
end
```

use

```
def authorizer
  return @authorizer if @authorizer
  client = Google::Auth::ClientId.new(Rails.application.credentials.google.fetch(:client_id), Rails.application.credentials.google.fetch(:client_secret))
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly']
  token_store =  Provider::GoogleAuthDbStore.new # <<<here
        
  @authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(client, scope, token_store, '/auth/google/callback')
  @authorizer
end
```